# How to scrape data from multiple wikipedia pages with R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, wikipedia

I am new to data scraping in R, but I would like to do the following. I have a list of celebrities, `celebs`, and I would like to grab their date of birth from Wikipedia. I know how to do it for each individual celebrity, but I am trying to animate this process.

```
celebs <- c("Tom Hanks", "Tim Cook", "Michael Bloomberg")
```

I do the following to get the information I need for the first celebrity, `Tom Hanks`.

```
library(rvest)

wiki <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Hanks")

birth_date <- wiki %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/text()') %>%
  html_text()
```

Is there a way to get the information I need for `Tim Cook` and `Michael Bloomberg` without manually editing the above code?

Answer (score 1):

welcome to SO.

To do any task repeatedly with code, you should always look to build a loop. Before you can build a loop, you should try to build a single iteration of the loop. You almost have that ready here, but there are a few missing steps.

First of all, we should try to generalize the code so that it could work by simply switch the value of one variable from your vector of iterators (celebs).

```
person <- "Tom Hanks"
```

Now, using that, we need to create the wikipedia link through code. There are two things to consider here:

1. We need to add the link before the name of the person;
2. We should replace the space in "Tom Hanks" for an underline

We can do that with this code:

```
link <- paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/", 
               str_replace_all(person, " ", "_"))
```

This creates the correct link, which we can use for the subsequent steps. Now, it is just a question of iterating through the `celebs` vector. There are many ways to do it, but in R, the most appropriate would be with an `sapply`. For that, we will create an anonymous function that will take a `person`'s name as input, query wikipedia and extract their birthday, using the code that you have already written:

```
function(person) {
    link <- paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/", 
                   str_replace_all(person, " ", "_"))

    wiki <- read_html(link)

    birth_date <- wiki %>%
        html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/text()') %>%
        html_text()
    return(birth_date)
}
```

You can now wrap an `sapply` structure around that:

```
birthdates <- sapply(celebs, function(person) {
    link <- paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/", 
                   str_replace_all(person, " ", "_"))

    wiki <- read_html(link)

    birth_date <- wiki %>%
        html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/text()') %>%
        html_text()
    return(birth_date)
})
```